# Pig: Load using AvroStorage throws "Cannot get schema from loadFunc" exception

Tags: apache-pig, avro

In hadoop, we got list of avro files stored under '/datasets/xyz/storm/information/'.

```
 -rw-r-----   3 storm XYZ    5570959 2015-10-01 01:46 /datasets/xyz/storm/information/storm_1443681972122.avro
 -rw-r-----   3 storm XYZ    5571687 2015-10-01 01:46 /datasets/xyz/storm/information/storm_1443681973303.avro
 -rw-r-----   3 storm XYZ    5632194 2015-10-01 01:46 /datasets/xyz/storm/information/storm_1443681975019.avro
```

What works?:

```
a= LOAD '/datasets/xyz/storm/information/storm_1443681975019.avro' USING AvroStorage ();
```

Avro Schema is defined in each avro file as the first record in below format:

```
 {header: (metadata_uuid: chararray,publishDate: chararray,eventDate: chararray),raw_data: chararray}
```

I would like to load all the avro file data at once into alias 'a'. So, I tried the below code:

```
a= = LOAD '/datasets/xyz/storm/information/' using AvroStorage();
```

I am getting exception as below:

```
ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage
```

I also tried providing schema explicitly as below:

```
 a= LOAD '/datasets/xyz/storm/information/' USING AvroStorage ('schema','{"header": ("metadata_uuid": "chararray","publishDate": "chararray","eventDate": "chararray"),"raw_data": "chararray"}');
```

Could you please tell me the right way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't find useful response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588911/cant-load-avro-schema-in-pig

Comment: Can you try : A = LOAD '/datasets/xyz/storm/information/*.avro' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();

Comment: @Murali Rao: Thanks for your response. Getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

The Schema provided is incorrect and also the format. I removed 'schema' from AvroStorage parameters.
I altered the script as below:

```
a= LOAD '/datasets/xyz/storm/information/' USING AvroStorage('{"type" : "record","name" : "DataRecord","namespace" : "com.bestbuy.sim.appTalkProjects.adobe.adobeClickStreamBDPSA.util","doc" : "Schema for com.bestbuy.sim.appTalkProjects.adobe.adobeClickStreamBDPSA.util.DataRecord","fields" : [ {"name" : "header","type" : [ "null", {"type" : "record","name" : "Header","doc" : "Schema for com.bestbuy.sim.appTalkProjects.adobe.adobeClickStreamBDPSA.util.Header","fields" : [ {"name" : "metadata_uuid","type" : [ "null", "string" ]}, {"name" : "publishDate","type" : [ "null", "string" ]}, {"name" : "eventDate","type" : [ "null", "string" ]} ]} ]}, {"name" : "raw_data","type" : [ "null", "string" ]} ]}');
```

This make the load to be successful.